# Vue.js - How to animate the list on removal of any item

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to animate the addition & removal of items in the array, everything is working fine. The only thing I am trying to figureout is, when I remove an item from the list the entire remaining items jumps up, I want to animate them by sliding up the list when any item is removed, How can I achieve this?

my sandbox is here : [SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-star-4ubit?file=/src/App.vue)

Vue code: `

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button @click="add" class="m-1" size="sm">Add</b-button>
    <b-button @click="remove" size="sm">Remove</b-button>
    <transition-group name="slide">
      <b-alert v-for="i in item" variant="success" :key="i" show>{{i}}</b-alert>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: true,
      item: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    remove() {
      this.item.splice(0, 1);
    },
    add() {
      this.item.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

`

My css:

```
<style>
.slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  animation: slide-out 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}
@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got some help from Bootstrap-vue community , special thanks to @hiws.
With some CSS change, We were able to achieve the functionality.

```
.slide-enter {


opacity: 0;
}

.slide-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.slide-enter-active {
  animation: slide-in 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.slide-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slide-out 0.5s ease-out forwards;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-out {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(350px);
  }
}
```